# How to find which component required a bean?

Tags: spring-boot

I have the error message "A component required a bean named XYZ that could not be found."

Is there a way to display, which component this is?

---

UPDATES:

This is the error message

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'demoAnnotation' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'demoAnnotation' in your configuration.
```

I have a bean defined called `demoAnnotation`:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("demoAnnotation")
public class Demo implements IDemo {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Demo.class);

    @Value("${com.example.demo.Demo.beanName:BEAN_NAME_DEFAULT}")
    private String beanName;

    @Override
    public String getBeanName() {
        return beanName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know bean name?

Answer (score 3):

When you start your application, you should get a message like: `Field repository in com.example.demo.Controller required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.Repository' that could not be found.`

com.example.demo.Controller is the name of the class that needs the com.example.demo.Repository bean

Then it would be easier if you show us the exact error message